# Site is not loading after relogin attempts on SSL

Tags: login, security

My site is no longer loading on my local machine. But I can load it from mobile.

I logged in then tried to relogin via HTTPS and it failed. After a few tries it put up a generic site is unavailable message. Now the site won't load at all. Safari says the server isn't responding.

I'm the site admin and I need to work on this site. I understand the need for security but I was already logged in and switched to SSL and it wouldn't accept my login and now my own site has blocked me somehow. Will normal functionality be restored?

**Update:**

It appears to be responding now. It has been roughly one hour so maybe something reset.

Comment: "Will normal functionality be restored?" - glad this is working now, but there's no way we could have answered this without more information or diagnostics from you. e.g. tcpdumps from both ends, web logs and syslogs on your host; can you connect using openssl s_client, has your host changed your site's IP address, and is there a bad cached DNS somewhere? Are you running fail2ban or similar which might have blocked your machine? etc.

Comment: It was security software on the server. I contacted my hosting company and they explained I had exceeded the maximum number of logins.